# Morris.js chart doesn't display properly within Polymer core-animated-pages > section > core-animated-pages > section > card > div

Tags: html, raphael, polymer

I'm designing a webpage using Polymer. There's a section within core-animated-pages that contains a card. I've got some javascript that generates a chart using Morris.js and inserts it into a div on the aforementioned card.

Here's the problem, no matter what width/height I set for that div the chart doesn't display properly. Here is a screenshot: **apparently I need more reputation for this?**

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agI3Z.jpg

But, if I resize the window (I've got Morris' resize function enabled), it resizes properly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX7Me.jpg

I've tried using Chart.js instead, but with that, the chart doesn't display at all. I'm confident it's not a problem with the JS, because if I copy the JS into JSBin, I can get the chart to display perfectly using both Morris and Chart.js

Here is some of the HTML where the morris chart is being inserted:

```html
<body unresolved fullbleed>
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;">

      <core-animated-pages id="selector" selected="0" transitions="hero-transition cross-fade-all cross-fade">
        <section id="lighting-analysis">
          <div id="headerpanel" hero-id="header" onclick="selectPage('selector', 0)" horizontal layout>
            <div hero hero-id="header1" flex style="background-color:white; height:100px; margin-right:-3px;"></div>
            <core-image hero hero-id="header2" src="header.png" height="100px" width="100px" sizing="cover" position="center"></core-image>
            <div hero hero-id="header3" flex style="background-color:white; height:100px; margin-left:-3px"></div>
          </div>

          <core-animated-pages id="form1" selected="0" transitions="slide-from-right" cross-fade>
            <section>
              <div class="card" slide-from-right>
                //blahblahblah
              </div>
            </section>
            <section>
              <div class="card" slide-from-right>
                //blahblahblah
              </div>
            </section>

            <section>
              <div class="card" slide-from-right style="height: 600px;">
                <div horizontal layout flex cross-fade>
                  <div class="nav" flex onclick="changePage('form1',0)">
                    <core-icon icon="arrow-back"></core-icon>PREV
                  </div>
                  <div class="nav" flex style="text-align:right;" onclick="changePage('form1',1)">
                    NEXT
                    <core-icon icon="arrow-forward"></core-icon>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Maintenance and Operation Cost ($)</p>

                <div id="morris-bar-chart" width="400px" height="400px"></div>

                <div id="SavingsComment" style="font-size:24px; text-align: center">
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </core-animated-pages>

        </section>
        <section id="lighting-designer">
        </section>

      </core-animated-pages>        
</div>
```

I'm pretty new to this an apologise if I'm missing something obvious, but I've spent too much time at this stage trying to work around it, so I think it's time to appeal to the community haha.

Thanks,
Nas

**UPDATE:** Ok so I've solved my own problem in an 'ugly' way I was trying to avoid. I've put the button that initiates the function that generates the graph on the same  as the graph will be displayed.

I'm guessing the problem was related to raphael grabbing the div dimensions while the div wasn't being displayed, resulting in weird sizing values. I tried a couple of workarounds but couldn't get any of them to work.

I've a feeling that core-animated-pages-transition-prepare may be intended to help in this exact situation, but I'm afraid I've no idea how to use it, and finding examples that I can understand is proving difficult.

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this, I'd greatly appreciate it. While it now 'works,' the fact that I've had to add unnecessary button presses for the user is making my brain itch.

**UPDATE 2:** So, I can't leave it alone.

I added this function, which is called when a button is clicked to go to the page where the graph is displayed and is passed the function to generate the graph.

```js
      function genGraph(func) {
        $("#form1").on("core-animated-pages-transition-end", func);
      }
```

But then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function

m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3
utils.fire @ polymer.js:9029
Polymer.mixin.complete @ core-animated-pages.html:394
(anonymous function) @ core-animated-pages.html:407
Job.complete @ polymer.js:8636
setTimeout (async)Job.go @ polymer.js:8621
job @ polymer.js:8647
base.job @ polymer.js:9779
Polymer.mixin.transitionEnd @ core-animated-pages.html:406
events.dispatchMethod @ polymer.js:9129
events.getEventHandler @ polymer.js:10713
utils.fire @ polymer.js:9029
Polymer.complete @ core-transition-pages.html:155
```

I'm guessing I'm not using the event properly. But this is as close as I've gotten.

This is the code from core-animated-pages.html that (I think) fires the event I'm trying to use to trigger my function:

```js
   complete: function() {
     if (this.animating) {
       this.cancelAsync(this.animating);
       this.animating = null;
     }
     this.transitioning.forEach(function(t) {
       t.removeAttribute('animate');
     });
     this.transitioning = [];
     this._transitionElements.forEach(function(transition) {
       transition.ensureComplete(this);
     }, this);
     this.fire('core-animated-pages-transition-end');
   },
```